# Switch visibility of element in onClick() method

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, visibility

I have an unordered list and a bunch of articles, all with absolute positions at the top of the page and hidden. Each article sits in a different div and has a different ID. I'd like to be able to click a list item and the corresponding article to become visible, and then when I click a different list item, the visible item disappears and the new article that corresponds with that article appears in its place.

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="articlelist">
        <ul>
            <li style="display:block;" onclick="document.getElementByClass('fullarticle').style.visibility='hidden'" onclick="document.getElementById('article1').style.visibility='visible'">ARTICLE 1</li>
            <li style="display:block;" onclick="document.getElementByClass('fullarticle').style.visibility='hidden'" onclick="document.getElementById('article2').style.visibility='visible'">ARTICLE 2</li>
            <li style="display:block;" onclick="document.getElementByClass('fullarticle').style.visibility='hidden'" onclick="document.getElementById('article3').style.visibility='visible'">ARTICLE 3</li>
            <li style="display:block;" onclick="document.getElementByClass('fullarticle').style.visibility='hidden'" onclick="document.getElementById('article4').style.visibility='visible'">ARTICLE 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="fullarticle" id="article1">
        <h1>ARTICLE 1</h1>
        <p>ABCDEFGH</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fullarticle" id="article2">
        <h1>ARTICLE 2</h1>
        <p>ABCDEFGH</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fullarticle" id="article3">
        <h1>ARTICLE 3</h1>
        <p>ABCDEFGH</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fullarticle" id="article4">
        <h1>ARTICLE 4</h1>
        <p>ABCDEFGH</p>
    </div>
```

and here's the CSS

```
.fullarticle {
  width: 61%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  float: left;
  position: absolute; top: 80px; left: 37%;
  visibility: hidden;
}


.articlelist {
  float: left;
  width: 37%;
}
```

Comment: Post your code and what you've tried please.

Comment: It would also be nice if you could also make a jsFiddle, so we can see it 'live' as well. Make one on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/97vmH/

Comment: @user2798841 Can you use jQuery?

Comment: I wrote something a while back that uses no jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/SujEb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use jQuery, you can do:

```
$('.articlelist ul li').click(function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    $('.fullarticle').hide();
    $('#article' + (i+1)).show();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97vmH/3/)**

Comment: I have another question if you think you could help. Is there a way that the article in the article list could be highlighted when it is selected, and then as I click another article from the list that becomes highlighted instead?

Comment: I am using this code. Is there a way that one div can displayed by default? At the minute, you must click to see any content at all.

Answer (score 3):

inside of the `head`:

```
var toggleVisibility = function(element) {
    if(element.style.visibility=='visible'){
        element.style.visibility='hidden';
    } else {
        element.style.visibility='visible';
    }
};
```

and then change the onclicks (if you *insist* on using them) to `onclick="toggleVisibility(document.getElementById('articleId'))"` where `articleID` is the ID of one of the article `div`s

**BUT**
hiding and showing content with `visibility` will keep the lower items under their invisible partners, so use `display` with `none` and `block` instead

```
var toggleVisibility = function(element) {
    if(element.style.display=='block'){
        element.style.display='none';
    } else {
        element.style.display='block';
    }
};
```

This is a little bit more complicated, but avoids importing the massive jQuery library for so small a task

Comment: You should use == operator there. I am editing your post.

Answer (score 2):

If you have jQuery:

```
<div class="articles">
<div class="articlelist">
    <ul>
        <li style="display:block;" onclick="toggleArticles('article1')">ARTICLE 1</li>
        <li style="display:block;" onclick="toggleArticles('article2')">ARTICLE 2</li>
        <li style="display:block;" onclick="toggleArticles('article3')">ARTICLE 3</li>
        <li style="display:block;" onclick="toggleArticles('article4')">ARTICLE 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="fullarticle" id="article1">
    <h1>ARTICLE 1</h1>
    <p>ABCDEFGH</p>
</div>
<div class="fullarticle" id="article2">
    <h1>ARTICLE 2</h1>
    <p>ABCDEFGH</p>
</div>
<div class="fullarticle" id="article3">
    <h1>ARTICLE 3</h1>
    <p>ABCDEFGH</p>
</div>
<div class="fullarticle" id="article4">
    <h1>ARTICLE 4</h1>
    <p>ABCDEFGH</p>
</div>
</div>

<script>
function toggleArticles(articleID) {
    $('#articles .fullArticle').hide(); // this hides all currently open articles (if any);
    $('#articles #' + articleID).show(); // show article
}
$('#articles .fullArticle').hide();
</script>
```